# Como comparar 2 listas e devolver uma outra lista com elementos iguais? - Haskell

Tags: lista, haskell

Meu código é esse

```
comparar :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
comparar [] [] = []
comparar (a:as) (b:bs) = [x | x <- as, x == b] ++ [x | x <- bs, x == a]
```

O que tem de errado no código acima?

Situação: quero aprender a encontrar elementos iguais em 2 listas ou mais, para fazer o MDC (Máximo Divisor Comum)

Exemplo: quero fazer o MDC da lista [150,200,300]

crio um função que gerar a lista de divisores de cada elementos

divisores 150 = [1,2,3,5,6,10,15,25,30,50,75,150]

divisores 200 = [1,2,4,5,8,10,20,25,40,50,100,200]

divisores 300 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,25,30,50,60,75,100,150,300]

comparo "divisores 150" com "divisores 200" com a função **comparar** (ou seja, o código lá em cima) e o resultado é [1,2,5,10,25,50] e depois comparo essa a nova lista com "divisores 300" que vai dar a mesma coisa, uso a função **Maior** para descobrir a maior número e esse será o MDC.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que percebi precisas de uma função que retira os elementos em comum de duas listas? Proposta da função:

```
comparar :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
comparar [] l  = []
comparar l  [] = []
comparar (h:t) l2
    | elem h l2 = h:comparar t l2
    | otherwise = comparar t l2
```

usando listas em compreensão fica mais simples:

```
comparar :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
comparar l l2 = [ x | x <- l , elem x l2]
```